# Dynamic loading of firebase modules? (v9)

Tags: javascript, firebase, dynamic, lazy-loading

I am using the newest Firebase version 9 and I was trying to optimize loading times. One way could be to dynamically load the firebase modules only when they are needed instead of waiting for all of them to be loaded. For example importing the `signOut()` function from `'firebase/auth'` only when the user clicks the sign out button. Would this strategy work? I am strugling to implement it on firebase 9. Are there any examples available?

So far I have tried:

index.js: the below code didn't work, aparently webpack could't compile (error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled)

```
let {signOut, signInAnonymously, etc.} = await import('firebase/auth');
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with lazy loading only Firestore. Usually, I don't need to load Firestore for every page as pages are SSR, the only time I need Firestore is when the user clicks "Load more".

I managed to do that with the code below (Firebase V9):

```
let database = null;

async function loadFirestore() {
  if (!database) {
    const { initializeApp } = await import('firebase/app');
    const { getFirestore } = await import('firebase/firestore');
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    database = getFirestore(app);
  }

  return database;
}

export { loadFirestore };
```

And then on my page:

```
const db = await loadFirestore();
const videoRef = doc(db, 'collection-name', id);
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear: unless you explicitly allow it in your webpack config, the `await` keyword cannot be used in top-level code.

That said, you don't need `await` on an import statement, as this is handled synchronously during the build already. As shown in the example in the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) like:

```
import { getAuth, signInAnonymously } from "firebase/auth";
```

So in your case, use:

```
import { signOut, signInAnonymously } from 'firebase/auth');
```

Comment: I specifically would like to avoid importing all firebase modules synchronously. Basically I want to dynamically import them only when needed to reduce my web app loading time.

Comment: There is no way to import only specific functions at that point: the browser can only import either the entire module, or nothing at all. If you want to benefit from tree shaking, you should use the import syntax I shared and do that on the server. If you want to dynamically load the necessary SDKs on the client, you can do so with a regular script import - but you will load the entire (non-tree shaken) SDK. See for example the imports in my script block here: https://jsbin.com/gekuqec/edit?html,console

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What would you recomend do reduce the loading time? Seems importing the modules using the format above (tree shaking) causes my boundle.js file to be very heavy (>200KB) just for importing database and authorization alone. The same js with only the "imports" in development mode is >2000KB. Is this to be expected?

Comment: The recommended way to reduce the load time is to let your bundler (typically webpack) get rid of the unused methods during the build. That's also the process that the documentation assumes and describes. If you think the result you get that way is too big, post a (new) question showing what you did and the result you get (in a way that we can reproduce it with copy/paste).

Comment: @blupotatos Any update here?

Comment: I created a new questions with details and code but so far no answers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70050721/firebase-version-9-taking-too-long-to-load